# NoMethodError: undefined method `zombie_url'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, tdd

Here is my test :

```
require 'test_helper'

class CreatingZombiesTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  setup { host! 'api.example.com' }

  test 'creates a new zombie' do
    post '/zombies',
      { zombie:
        { name: 'brain_eater', weapon: 'teeth'}
      }.to_json,
      { 'Accept' => Mime::JSON, 'Content-Type' => Mime::JSON.to_s }

      assert_equal 201, response.status

    end
  end
```

And controller :

```
def create
    @zombie = Zombie.new(zombie_params)
    if @zombie.save
      render json: @zombie, status: 201, location: @zombie
    end
  end
```

I keep getting this error, search was not useful.

```
CreatingZombiesTest#test_creates_a_new_zombie:
NoMethodError: undefined method `zombie_url' for #<Api::ZombiesController:0x007f8ef9f6cd60>
    app/controllers/api/zombies_controller.rb:22:in `create
```

Routes :

```
  Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                 Controller#Action
    api_zombies GET    /zombies(.:format)          api/zombies#index {:subdomain=>"api"}
                POST   /zombies(.:format)          api/zombies#create {:subdomain=>"api"}
 new_api_zombie GET    /zombies/new(.:format)      api/zombies#new {:subdomain=>"api"}
edit_api_zombie GET    /zombies/:id/edit(.:format) api/zombies#edit {:subdomain=>"api"}
     api_zombie GET    /zombies/:id(.:format)      api/zombies#show {:subdomain=>"api"}
                PATCH  /zombies/:id(.:format)      api/zombies#update {:subdomain=>"api"}
                PUT    /zombies/:id(.:format)      api/zombies#update {:subdomain=>"api"}
                DELETE /zombies/:id(.:format)      api/zombies#destroy {:subdomain=>"api"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I solved it, 
it should be

```
location: api_zombie_url(zombie)
```

I need the api_ in my route because my controller is inside an Api namespace, so zombie_url was not defined, but api_zombie_url is defined.

Comment: This might be worth some additional commentary as to why this fixed the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Did you setup routes.rb? ie:

```
 post 'zombie/create'
```

run

```
rake routes
```

in your terminal and get the corresponding link. Note - If your link is zombie_create, then you will have to append path or url depending on what you are trying to accomplish. (zombie_create_url OR zombie_create_path)

Comment: What is get 'zombie/create' ? It's a POST method. My routes are ok

Comment: sorry.. still early. Your controller method is create. I assumed it was in the zombie controller. None of your routes have a create.. So I assumed you are missing it from routes.rb.. I will update answer.

Comment: check my routes, I posted them. And it's post '/zombies' , there is no create in it.

Comment: Just because the comment says create does not mean it points to the create method..